# Why Android Studio kill Intellij Idea java processes?

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea

When I close my Android Studio project, the Intellij Idea running processes are also killed.
Both IDE use gradle build project, I think it's related.

How to avoid this?

Comment: Does it happen only with Android Studio? What happens if you do vice versa? Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185242 This is fixed in IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.2 version and should appear in Android Studio later versions.

Comment: Try if adding this option into [Help | Edit Custom Properties](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869) and IDE restart helps: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185242#focus=Comments-27-3039905.0-0

Answer (score 1):

I edit my Android Studio custom properties, add the following line.

```
idea.gradle.disableDaemonsStopOnExit=true
```

And restart, it's fixed! It's an IDE issue [jetbrains.com/issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185242#focus=Comments-27-3039905.0-0).

Thanks [@Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64364516/why-android-studio-kill-intellij-idea-java-processes?noredirect=1#comment113820212_64364516) comment.